# Received Memory Warning [Level 1]

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

In my project I am receiving this error

> Received Memory Warning [level 1]

I have checked through build and analysis and Instruments. There are no leaks present but still when I debug the application in device I get this error in console. Can anyone suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that you're using a lot of memory and available memory is low. This warning can happen, for example, if you are loading lots of images. The warning exists so that you can free any cached data, unload views that aren't visible, etc. as needed to avoid a crash, e.g. in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. This is not (necessarily) an error or bug in your code.